# Is the Framekiller really safe against clickjacking?

Tags: client-side, clickjacking, iframe

I am using this code.
In the header section of the page, this CSS rule:

```
html{display:none;}
```

And then this javascript:

```
if (self == top)
  document.documentElement.style.display = 'block';
else
  top.location = self.location;
```

Can I consider it safe against clickjacking from mobile devices?
If not, do I have to add other protections like the `X-Frame-Options` header, or others?

Comment: Note: this question is different from:
http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/103207/should-one-use-framekiller-code-avoid-others-embedding-https-pages-in-iframes
since i'm asking for a specific implementation of it

Comment: Note: Most importantly it will render the whole site useless for anyone having javascript disabled and will reduce the overall performance of the website especially on mobile devices. You are better off using the X-Frame-Options Header from performance and usability reasons.

Comment: No, it will render the page useless, that is exactly what i want. Also in 2016 i think nobody has phones with browsers without javascript.

Answer (score 8):

In my opinion there's no such thing as a frame killer/buster script as JavaScript can be disabled in the `<iframe` tag, rendering your code useless.

The best way to protect your application from clickjacking attacks, for modern browsers, is configuring your web server to send the `X-Frame-Options` in the response header.

Configuring this is quite easy:

**Apache**
In `httpd.conf` add: `Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN`

**Nginx**
In `nginx.conf` add: `add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";`

Comment: In the Apache header, `set` instead of `append` would be probably better. The point is that `set` will override this header if is already set.

Comment: Ah you mean from an application perspective to override it server side. Yeah, I guess that's an idea depending on the requirements.

Comment: If Javascript is disabled, you don't see the anything... There is the css rule :html{display:none;}